# How can I fix kernelevent tracing, error 0xc0000035?

Tags: windows-8, kernel

I have noticed several kernelevent tracing errors in event viewer. The code is always 0xc0000035 and event ID is always 2.

```
Session "HomeGroupLog" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Session "P2PLog" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Session "IDListenLog" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Session "NegoLog" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Session "Pku2uLog" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035
```

What could be causing those and how to fix it?
I'm on windows 8.1.

Thanks.

Comment: 0xC0000035 = path issue (ERROR_BAD_NETPATH or STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION). Have you moved any Windows folders from C: to a different drive?

Comment: Not really, I haven't.